# Refresh only selected area in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, random, google-sheets, refresh, custom-function

I'm doing some D20/RPG stuff where everything is based on different dice / randbetween.

I want to be able to refresh certain areas and not the whole sheet, but the only option is cmd-r and it refreshes all of them.

Anyone got an idea for this? Some scripting perhaps?

As an alternative I looked at other solutions. One where a function would hard copy the value from cell A1 (with a randbetween function) to A2 IF A3=1. IF A3 is not 1, the value of A2 would stay put. My plan was to simply hide A1, present A2 and use A3 as an on/off button. Haven't figured out how to do this either... Any idea?

Thanks in advance, I spent hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheets, rebranded as Google Sheets, doesn't include a function to refresh only certain areas. Instead consider to use a script triggered by a button, by a custom menu or a custom function.

If you decide to use a custom function, bear in mind that custom functions arguments should be deterministic. From [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

> That is, built-in spreadsheet functions that return a different result
> each time they calculate — such as NOW() or RAND() — are not allowed
> as arguments to a custom function. If a custom function tries to
> return a value based on one of these volatile built-in function, it
> will display Loading... indefinitely.

Related

- [Custom Functions and Recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163243/1595451)
- [Google sheet cell recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53616111/1595451)