# Custom Functions and Recalculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a custom function that accepts three range names as input parameters. When values of cells in these ranges change, the function output stays the same. This is a "feature" of the platform.

Is there any proper way (as of yet) to make custom functions in Google Sheets recalculate dynamically? I know people have tried adding `now()` as a parameter, which used to continuously recalculate regardless of need. (Now blocked in new sheets.) Has anyone found a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to make a custom function recalculate is to change an argument of it. Regarding the use of `NOW()` and other similar built-in functions as arguments of custom functions, from [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> Custom function arguments must be [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm). That is, built-in
> spreadsheet functions that return a different result each time they
> calculate — such as NOW() or RAND() — are not allowed as arguments to
> a custom function. If a custom function tries to return a value based
> on one of these volatile built-in function, it will display Loading...
> indefinitely.

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163243/custom-functions-and-recalculation#comment63813377_29906331) by [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) to this answer:

> In fact, rather than "Loading...", this will display an `#ERROR!`, *This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()*

Comment: In fact, rather than "Loading...", this will display an `#ERROR!`, _This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()_

Answer (score 5):

*The Problem:-*

A custom script on a cell of a spreadsheet will only execute itself when the parameters of our custom function defined on the cell have changed or have been manipulated. If they remain same, the earlier result is driven from the cache.

*Possible Solutions:-*

**A)**

Obviously you may use Now() on any cell and then pass that cell to your function parameter. Make sure to change the spreadsheet settings -> calculation -> onchange every minute.
(This will change the parameter of the function every minute and thus the script will be executed)

> Updated Spreadsheet doesn't seem to be allowing Now() or Rand() or such
>   functions anymore to be passed indirectly/directly to the custom
>   function.

**B)**

Add a 'Refresh' menu item and maybe go to your script and define a function which changes the value of a cell when you click the 'Refresh' menu. Pass the value as a parameter to your function where you are executing your script.

**C)**

Go to your script and make a function. Let's say updateCellValue(). Now define the same logic here which is aimed at changing the value of a cell.

Example: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());`

Now go to Edit->Current Project's trigger and create a trigger that will trigger your function (updateCellValue) after every custom-defined time limit. This will do the same thing as solution B but you won't have to click the Refresh button of menu.

> Seems like a bit of hack but probably I feel that's the only way as of now to
>   update the spreadsheet for custom-defined functions like fetching data
>   dynamically from a server.

Comment: Thanks for this (Option C)! I tried it but it wipes out my date formatting (which I need to be a specific pattern). Do you know how I could maintain the formatting and just update the value?

Comment: A demo that may help here: 
How to Auto Refresh the ImportXML formula in Google Sheets with Apps Script Trigger
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R34jC_hxFxo

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2KzgMEn2

https://i.imgur.com/Nrx6iYW.mp4

Comment: As unix timestamp:
https://pastebin.com/XJ6MWhN6
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246058/10789707
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71695136/10789707

Comment: Math.floor() needed to get unixtimestamp as int:
https://pastebin.com/XQf3YN1t
also this helped get past days unix timestamps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74354879/10789707