# How to get Unix time as integer format in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to use unix time stamp for count-up nonce in GAS.

```
var nonce = Math.floor((date.getTime()/1000))
```

is my first idea.  But GAS handles this variant as `1.482239855E9` - 9th Gig format - instead of `1482239855`.
When I connect it with other strings, it shows `1482239855my_string`, which is good.

The problem is I send this nonce to server with encrypted `1482239855my_string` for authentication then the nonce will not match as `1.482239855E9` vs `1482239855`.
How can I get this nonce as integer format?  In spreadsheet, I know `setNumberFormat("0")` method in `range`. Is there a similar method or properties?

Comment: Hmmmmm.  I used `nonce = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "yyyyMMddHHmmss");` and worked ok.  Any other ways??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `nonce` is already an integer, the exponential format is just how it is presented for display on screen by `Logger.log`. Its string representation obtained with `toString` (which is also called implicitly when you concatenate with another string) has ordinary format, and can be safely used for information exchange.

```
var date = new Date();
var nonce = Math.floor((date.getTime()/1000)).toString(); // is "1482247966"
```

Comment: ah, the toString method is really simple. Thank you zaq!!

Answer (score 2):

In Google Apps Script, you can obtain Unix Timestamp with the following code.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
Logger.log(timestamp.toString());
```