# Google Scripts functions refreshing rate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a simple function to get some cell value

```
function getValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];

  var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C4");

  var cell = range.getCell(1, 1); // "C2"
  if (cell.isBlank()) {
      return 'error'
  } else {
      return cell.getValue()  
  }
}
```

But when I change data in `C2`, cell, which contains `=getValue()` function does not refresh itself instantly. Only if I run script again and get back to sheet. Is it possible to speed this process up? Any code for this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe when you manually enter data into a cell with a formula that you overwrite the formula.  I'm not sure what the point of this function is but if you want to get it work you might consider an `onEdit()` function.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a script custom function `=getValue()` instead of something like `=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"error",C2)`?

Comment: Related: [Custom functions and recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163243/1595451)

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the custom functions for this situation, how about this workaround? I don't know whether this is the best way for you. Please think of this as one of several answers.

The flow of script is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve all values and formulas on the sheet.
2. Remove values of cells which have formulas.
3. Reflect values to the sheet using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.
4. Import formulas to the removed cells.

**By `onEdit()`, when you edit the cell, this sample script is launched.**

#### Sample script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.source.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var values = data.map(function(e){return e.slice()});
  for (var i in formulas) {
    for (var j in formulas[i]) {
      if (formulas[i][j]) {
        data[i][j] = formulas[i][j];
        values[i][j] = "";
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

#### Note :

- In this situation which imports a value at "C2" to the cell at `=getValue()`, the refresh speed is slower than that of @random-parts's method.
- To use `onEdit()` is also proposed from @Cooper.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.